# How to create OpenSea collection that includes more than one contract address?

Tags: opensea

In OpenSea [documentation](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/collection-model) is said that Collections are used to represent all the assets in a single (**or multiple**) contract addresses and help users group items from the same creator.

Collection has **primary_asset_contracts** attribute with description "A list of the contracts that are associated with this collection".

But there is neither API, neither UI solution to include additional contract address to collection. So how collection with more than one contract address can be created?

Comment: It seems to me that the docs are a bit confusing. There's no clear way how this is processed. Can I add any NFT address to the `primary_asset_contracts` or do I have to be the owner? This section of the [docs](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-collections-testnets) says "many ERC-721 contracts may all belong to the same collection (dapp)". So I think it is possible. I added `primary_asset_contracts` and added an array of ERC721 addresses owned, minted and deployed by the same address but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: My second thought is, that it is not possible. `primary_asset_contracts` is only mentioned in the API docs. So I think it's an internal key OpenSea uses to create collections for the same issuer. But a collection itself only has one contract in it.

Comment: @JonasMerhej I have to agree with you here. Feels like docs are misleading. I tried to contact Opensea, but no answer yet.

Comment: This is the answer I got from OpenSea support on Discord "Not possible for now. You'll have to contact us if you want to merge contracts/collections". I then asked what if I have couple of thousands of Adresses that I want to add to a collection and this is what they answered: "You'll have to contact us through https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/requests/new"

Comment: This is the answer I got in the support ticket:



Hi there,
Thanks for reaching out. We would be able to merge collections on our end if its owned by the same creator.
If you have multiple collections, we could merge it under on slug an example of a slug would be (brkfst-world); https://opensea.io/collection/brkfst-world 
If this is something your interested in doing please include a link to each of the collections and the slug you'd like to merge it under.
Kind regards,
OpenSea Customer Experience Associate

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I got from OpenSea support:

> Hi there, Thanks for reaching out. We would be able to merge
> collections on our end if its owned by the same creator. If you have
> multiple collections, we could merge it under on slug an example of a
> slug would be (brkfst-world);
> https://opensea.io/collection/brkfst-world  If this is something your
> interested in doing please include a link to each of the collections
> and the slug you'd like to merge it under. Kind regards, OpenSea
> Customer Experience Associate

Merge into one collection can't be done using API or UI, but OpenSea can do it on their end if they are contacted.